# How to retrieve subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got mongo collection in my database:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab08c",
        "lang": "en",
        "__v": 0,
        "message_subsets": [
            {
                "identifier": "errors",
                "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab08d",
                "messages": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "invalid",
                        "message_text": "$FIELD$ is invalid",
                        "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab091"
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "empty",
                        "message_text": "$FIELD$ is required",
                        "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab090"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "59955bb0cd522a00bcaab08c",
        "lang": "ru",
    ...
]
```

which was constructed by this mongoose schema:

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    identifier: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    message_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
});

const MessageSubsetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    identifier: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    messages: [MessageSchema]
});

const LangMessageSetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lang: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    message_subsets: [MessageSubsetSchema]
});
```

I want to retrieve all `messages` from `message_subsets` array item which has `"identifier": "errors"` if their parent has `"lang": "en"`.
Because of I'm a little new to mongoose and mongo I stuck with that!!! Can you help me to make that data query the right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Collection.find({'messages.message_subsets.identifier':'errors', 'lang': 'en'}, {'messages': 1})
```

Comment: Yes, but not exactly. I'd like to retrieve only messages array.

Comment: @bashkovpd I've updated. It's called projection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I'm doing something wrong but that query returns only _id of main parent element (where `lang` specified).

Comment: As you ve used mongoose you can query directly over your Schema, use `MessageSchema.find({'message_subsets.identifier':'errors', 'lang': 'en'}, {'messages': 1})`